# Is this old question about git not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

I stumbled upon this question [How do I edit git's history to correct an incorrect email address/name](https://serverfault.com/questions/12373/how-do-i-edit-gits-history-to-correct-an-incorrect-email-address-name) from google and was surprised to find it here on SF. 
I did notice it's very old (5 years) so just out of curiosity, was it not off-topic *then* or is it not off-topic even now? If it is, should it be migrated to SO?

Comment: These days I generally send people who ask git questions back to SO where they will get a better audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how that escaped notice for so long, why it got so many upvotes, or why it was posted here in the first place. It's very obviously a question for Stack Overflow, and so I've closed it. (Questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.)

Comment: The huge number of up-votes is almost certainly that they were slowly added over the last 5 years by people who found it via Google long after it fell off the front page and voted up because it was what they Googled for. He only got a handful of up votes when it was first posted; and IIRC that was long enough ago that the current level of hostility to lower skill level questions wasn't nearly as strong here as it is today.

Comment: @DanNeely The problem with the question isn't the skill or lack thereof of the person asking, it is the subject matter. While system administrators do occasionally use git, this particular task is one that is almost always done by developers in the process of managing their source code. Thus it is a better fit for [so].

Comment: Wouldn't locked as a historically significant question have been more appropriate than closed as off-topic?

Comment: @kasperd Locking it would prevent anyone from editing the question or the answers. Since this has had recent edits, I don't think it _yet_ needs to be locked. The most important part is making the point that git usage questions are generally a better fit elsewhere.